# Find minimum queue size among threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduling, task-queue

I am trying to implement a new scheduling technique with Multithreads. Each Thread has it own private local queue. The idea is, each time the task is created from the program thread, it should search the minimum queue sizes ( a queue with less number of tasks) among the queues and enqueue in it. 
A way of load balancing among threads, where less busy queues enqueued more.

Can you please suggest some logics (or) idea how to find the minimum size queues among the given queues dynamically in programming point of view.

I am working on visual studio 2008, C++ programming language in our own multithreading library implementing a multi-rate synchronous data flow paradigm .

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a *single* queue across all threads? Then the issue of balancing queue sizes would not arise.

Comment: @NPE: with multiple queues, you can efficiently implement them with single writer/reader pattern.

Comment: @NPEyes using Thread local queues will efficiently implement each threads with single writer/reader pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to try this, can each queue not just keep a public 'int count' member, updated with atomic inc/dec as tasks are pushed/popped?

Whether such a design is worth the management overhead and the occasional 'mistakes' when a task is queued to a thread that happens to be running a particularly lengthy job when another thread is just about to dequeue a very short job, is another issue.

Comment: So is it like making a private int count for each queue, increasing its count when the tasks are pushed, decreasing its count when popped, and the tasks are dispatched to the queues seeing this count.

Comment: Yes - iterate the queues and dispatch the task to the queue with the lowest, (or first zero found), count.

Comment: As you said, not perfectly synchronized, but probably the easiest and most performant solution.

Comment: @MartinJames:Yes the another issue as you said will be a problem as we dont know the exactly the execution time of each tasks. but i think usually the processing time for tasks performed by the threads are somewhat equivalent? is it true?

Comment: @rahul, I don't know - they're your tasks, you should know :)

Comment: Possible optimization - init. the count to 1 and do the count decrement when a work thread visits the queue to try and pop a task.  This allows the count to indicate whether a thread is really idle, (count=0), or processing the last task from its queue, (count=1).

Answer (score 1):

As you see trying to find the less loaded queue is cumbersome and could be an inefficient method as you may add more work to queues with only one heavy task, whereas queues with small tasks will have nor more jobs and become quickly inactive.

You'd better use a **work-stealing** heuristic : when a thread is done with its own jobs it will look at the other threads queues and "steal" some work instead of remaining idle or be terminated.

Then the system will be auto-balanced with each thread being active until there is not enough work for everyone.

You should not have a situation with idle threads and work waiting for processing.

Comment: +1, This is better, but more complex to achieve with lock-free queues - the queues have multiple consumers.  I know that work-stealing pools exist, just not sure how they work internally.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't the threads fetching their work from a 'master' work queue ?

If you are really trying to distribute work items from a master source, to a set of workers, you are then doing load balancing, as you say.  In that case, you really are talking about scheduling, unless you simply do round-robin style balancing.  Scheduling is a very deep subject in Computing, you can easily spend weeks, or months learning about it.

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP wants to use lock-free queues and is hoping that the elimination of lock overhead will outweigh the queue-iteration overhead and the possibility of incorrect queueing decisions that leave job/s stuck on a queue to a busy thread when another thread becomes free.  I'm not convinced it's a good design, but I haven't tried anything like it, so don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could synchronise a counter among the threads. But I guess this isn't what you want.

Since you want to implement everything using dataflow, everything should be queues.

Your first option is to query the number of jobs inside a queue. I think this is not easy, if you want a single reader/writer pattern, because you probably have to use lock for this operation, which is not what you want. Note: I'm just guessing, that you can't use lock-free queues here; either you have a counter or take the difference of two pointers, either way you have a lock.

Your second option (which can be done with lock-free code) is to send a command back to the dispatcher thread, telling him that worker thread x has consumed a job. Using this approach you have n more queues, each from one worker thread to the dispatcher thread.

Comment: on your 2nd option, you said 'you have n more queues, each from one worker thread to the dispatcher thread'. i am not clear about it. can you please explain a bit clear

Comment: @rahul: at the moment you have one queue per thread, right? you could add another queue per thread, so you have two queues per thread. one for sending jobs to the thread and in the other direction for telling the dispatcher thread that one job is consumed from the queue.